# Pika hangs when closing the consumers

Tags: python-3.x, rabbitmq, pika

I'm using pika on python3 to consume a queue on RabbitMQ. My consumer is supposed to stop/be killed on certain events, and thus it should be able to handle the closing of channels and connections by itself. After some running, I found out that I had a lot of "zombie consumers" (for want of a better term, they are registered consumers on the Rabbit, with their unacked messages lying around, but often do not have a matching process anymore) left hanging around.

After some experiments I found out that, when I try to run a `channel.cancel()` the process just hangs until something else comes to kill it and then the consumer is considered still active by Rabbit for some time (I think about 20 minutes).

My code works like this:

```py
def do_some_work(method_frame, body):
  # something happens here
  if condition:
       logging.info("Closing up...")
       requeue = channel.cancel()
       logging.info("Consumer stopped, {0} messages sent back".format(requeue))

for method_frame, properties, body in channel.consume(args.queue):
    do_some_work(method_frame, body)
```

When `condition` is met, I can see the first log line and the requests to get more messages from Rabbit stop (at least this is what I can tell from Rabbit), but the process effectively hangs without closing the channels and connection, until clean ups from Rabbit and the OS happen.

Comment: Please provide a complete, runnable script that I can use to reproduce this issue, and post it to the [Pika mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/pika-python). That is by far the fastest way to get help.